# showing tag beside catagory

Tags: tags, conditional-tags, categories, template-tags

thanks for your guidance, here is one last but not least thing for me to learn,

i am using Today news wordpress theme, since with your help i have moved my process from category to tag based archiving, my theme give me shortcodes to display post list from specific category, like this

[blog1 items=1 cat=op-ed]

here "op-ed" is my category, and it show like this

(add http:// in below links)

s15.postimg.org/g1s8k8cmz/image.jpg

s15.postimg.org/oy30o6397/image.jpg

if you need i can attache the theme files. 
PS , the goal is to replace category based sorting to tag based like you helped me earlier.

the code that generated this short info is 
http://pastebin.com/qpLyeSsF

```
    <?php
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term = $queried_object->name;
add_shortcode("blog1", "blog_one");



function blog_one($atts, $content) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(

        "items" => 4,

        "cat" => null,

        "id" => null,

        "nav" => false,

        "order" => "desc",

        "orderby" => "DATE",

        "events" => null

    ), $atts));

    $order       = strtoupper($order);

    $items_count = 0;

    $items_src   = null;

    if ($id == null) {

        $query          = array(

            'orderby' => $orderby,

            'order' => $order,

            'posts_per_page' => $items,

            'category_name' => $cat

        );

        $wp_query_event = new WP_Query($query);

    }

    $items_src .= '

<div id="short-one" class="fixed">';

    while ($wp_query_event->have_posts()):

        $wp_query_event->the_post();

        global $post;

        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

        $cover    = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'short-one');

        $no_cover = get_template_directory_uri();

        $category = get_the_category();

        $vimeo    = get_post_meta($post->ID, "post_vimeo", true);

        $youtube  = get_post_meta($post->ID, "post_youtube", true);

                $author   = get_the_author_meta('ID');

        $items_src .= '

        <div class="short-one-art">

                <div class="short-one-cover">';

        if ($vimeo or $youtube) {

            $items_src .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><div class="short-one-video"></div></a>';

        }

        $items_src .= '

                        <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';

        if ($image_id) {

            $items_src .= '<img src="' . $cover[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';

        } else {

            $items_src .= '<img src="' . $no_cover . '/images/no-cover/short-one.png" alt="no-cover" />';

        }

        $items_src .= '</a>

                        <div class="comment-bubble">

                                <span class="comment-count">' . get_comments_number() . '</span>

                        </div>';

        if ($cat != null) {

        } else {

            $items_src .= '            

                        <div class="slider-left-cat">' . $category[0]->cat_name . '</div>';

        }

        $items_src .= '</div>

                <h2><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>

                <div class="short-one-info">' . get_the_date('F jS, Y') . ' | by <a href="' . get_author_posts_url($author) . '">' . get_the_author() . '</a> | <a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID).'">'. $category[0]->cat_name .'</a></div>

                ' . get_excerpt(230) . '

        </div><!-- end .short-one-art -->';

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();

    $items_src .= '

</div><!-- end #short-one -->

';

    return $items_src;

}
```

let me know if you need any more lead to this culprit

thanks

Comment: Please post your code inside your question

Comment: @PieterGoosen added the code, plus visit the site , that will give you clear idea

http://ca.unitysofts.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this code along side the code given by you
I have not tested the code but it should do the trick...

where you used this `[blog1 items=1 cat=op-ed]` replace this with this `[blogtag items=1 tag=china]`

```
  <?php
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term = $queried_object->name;
add_shortcode("blogtag", "blog_tag");



function blog_tag($atts, $content) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(

        "items" => 4,

        "tag" => null,

        "id" => null,

        "nav" => false,

        "order" => "desc",

        "orderby" => "DATE",

        "events" => null

    ), $atts));

    $order       = strtoupper($order);

    $items_count = 0;

    $items_src   = null;

    if ($id == null) {

        $query          = array(

            'orderby' => $orderby,

            'order' => $order,

            'posts_per_page' => $items,

            'tag' => $tag

        );

        $wp_query_event = new WP_Query($query);

    }

    $items_src .= '

<div id="short-one" class="fixed">';

    while ($wp_query_event->have_posts()):

        $wp_query_event->the_post();

        global $post;

        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

        $cover    = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'short-one');

        $no_cover = get_template_directory_uri();

        $tag      = get_the_tags();

        $vimeo    = get_post_meta($post->ID, "post_vimeo", true);

        $youtube  = get_post_meta($post->ID, "post_youtube", true);

        $author   = get_the_author_meta('ID');

        $items_src .= '

        <div class="short-one-art">

                <div class="short-one-cover">';

        if ($vimeo or $youtube) {

            $items_src .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><div class="short-one-video"></div></a>';

        }

        $items_src .= '

                        <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';

        if ($image_id) {

            $items_src .= '<img src="' . $cover[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';

        } else {

            $items_src .= '<img src="' . $no_cover . '/images/no-cover/short-one.png" alt="no-cover" />';

        }

        $items_src .= '</a>

                        <div class="comment-bubble">

                                <span class="comment-count">' . get_comments_number() . '</span>

                        </div>';

        if ($tag != null) {

        } else {

            $items_src .= '            

                        <div class="slider-left-cat">' . $tag[0]->name . '</div>';

        }

        $items_src .= '</div>

                <h2><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>

                <div class="short-one-info">' . get_the_date('F jS, Y') . ' | by <a href="' . get_author_posts_url($author) . '">' . get_the_author() . '</a> | <a href="'.get_tag_link($tag[0]->term_id).'">'. $tag[0]->name .'</a></div>

                ' . get_excerpt(230) . '

        </div><!-- end .short-one-art -->';

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();

    $items_src .= '

</div><!-- end #short-one -->

';

    return $items_src;

}
```

Comment: it works perfect guru, you have taught me a new way of approach, appreciate that, may be i have last one or tow questions that i will ask in new post, but your help, gave me milage. 

thanks